# A strange hurry to get an answer

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

In several months since I have been re-registered, I have observed that some users are in an unusual hurry to receive a response. I was asking myself these days if some users ask a question at an exam stage, or have to do some exams, or some competitions. How should I behave?

Comment: You can purposefully wait another two days before posting an answer, or you can inquire why the rush, some people will outright tell you that they are trying to cheat.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It can be a solution. But there are other users that get them quickly an answer. I am not capable of cheating or telling falsehoods.

Comment: You can't control others. You can only control yourself.

Comment: If the posts are of inadequate quality/show no effort on the asker's part you can vote to close/downvote/provide a comment asking for their attempts. Otherwise, even if the asker is in a hurry, a well-written contextual question should not deserve penalty unless it is part of an ongoing contest or something.

Comment: If you have evidence that a question is from an ongoing competition, Sebastiano, then you can flag the question for moderator attention and cite your evidence. Moderators have the option of locking the question until such time as the competition is over.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I give to you and all users Will Jagy,   Asaf Karagila, Gerry Myerson my sincere thank you very much for your collaboration. All the best.

Comment: "You can't control others. You can only control yourself." I do admire (and am trying harder to live by) this motto, advising us to not let other's actions fill all of our time, but I gotta point out that while that is technically true, all of us here, some more than others, can and do control what is allowed to appear on the math.se website. And I"m bothering to point this out because we're in a political moment now where people feel powerless to prevent horrible behavior. I don't want to promote busy-body-ism, but I"d like to be in a world where more people act to prevent bad.

Comment: Also, note that *urgent!!!* questions may not just be posted during an exam, but an hour before, or the night before, homework is due, homework that some askers wait until the last minute to do.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Your words are beautiful in content and in substance. I agree them, and I also live these words in my daily life. I believe that the selfishness, the wickedness, the lies, the oppression, the lies have penetrated our lives like a hurricane of which I don't even see the end. The evil in my humble opinion is trendy.

Comment: @amWhy There are some very, very low-level questions even how they are written and I think they can be a wake-up call that is something immediate. I think, and I hope the users agree, not to answer these kind of questions and to wait a few days. It could be a solution as indicated by Asaf Karagila.

Comment: Indeed, @Sabastiano.  Plus, a little respectful "peer pressure" to those who might want to answer, anyway, can go a long way, in addition to some of us refusing to answer such questions.  Your post here helps in that respect.

Comment: I've always treated words like "urgent" in questions as a sign to either delay answering them for a week or so, or not to answer them at all.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician This is a optimal suggestion.

Comment: With COVID and shutdowns of schools/colleges in various parts of the world, number of these requests could be from live online tests where an answer needs to be uploaded very soon, so waiting on answers is definitely a good idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I’ve seen questions like this and it’s always a huge red flag for me.

Usually I say something to the effect of

> Why is it so urgent? If you are attempting to cheat on an assignment, this will not be tolerated.

and then I flag for mod intervention.

A few weeks ago, a user accidentally admitted to attempting to cheat and then edited it out of the post. I got mods involved and asked everyone to delete their answers.

I would like to know what mods can/usually do if cheating does successfully occur.

Comment: Cheating does successfully occur, so you can remove the "if".

Comment: @user21820 I know it does, hence my anecdote

Comment: I was just kind of joking, because "A if B" is equivalent to "A" if "B" is already true. Of course, what you actually meant was "what mods can/usually do when cheating occurs". =P

Comment: @user21820 I guess I don’t get the joke. I think it’s just normal conditional syntax because the cheating has to occur before the mods can do anything about it. I’m probably overthinking this, I tend to do that 

Comment: The joke is that "cheating successfully occurs" is a complete sentence all by itself and is true, whereas you obviously meant the "if" in each case separately. Never mind; I should probably not joke around too much. =P